# Ajaxcontoltoolkit tab container not displaying alongisde modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using VS2010, C#, ASP.NET, I've inserted Ajax Control Toolkit Tab Container which works great, but when I insert a modal popup extender on another panel, tabs do not display! what is going wrong here? How can I have both on them as both are really cool effects

thanks

my tab container:

```
<cc1:TabContainer runat="server" ID="Tabs" CssClass="visoft__tab_xpie7" 
        ActiveTabIndex="2" Width="100%" Height="160px">
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tab1" HeaderText="برنامه نویسی وب و اتوماسیون">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <div  >
            <asp:Image ID="Image12"  BorderStyle="None" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/internet.png" /><br />

                وب و اتوماسیون
            </div> 
                        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                             <div runat="server" id="divTab1" style="direction:rtl;">
             </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
```

```
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tab2" HeaderText="تله متری" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <div  >
            <asp:Image ID="Image11"  BorderStyle="None" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/telemetry.png" /><br />

                تله متری
            </div> 
                        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                             <div runat="server" id="divTab2" style="direction:rtl;">
             </div>
```

```
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tab3" HeaderText="">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <div >
            <asp:Image ID="Image10" BorderStyle="None" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/mb.png" /><br />

                موبایل، گرافیک، بازی
            </div> 
                        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                                             <div runat="server" id="divTab3" style="direction:rtl;">
             </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
```

```
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" ID="TabPanel1" HeaderText="">
        <HeaderTemplate>
        <div >
            <asp:Image ID="Image13" BorderStyle="None" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/flash.png" /><br />

                انیمیشن و فلش
            </div> 
                        </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                                             <div runat="server" id="divTab4" style="direction:rtl;">
             </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
```

my modal popup extender:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNews1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup"  >
    <div style="height:100% ;  overflow:auto; width: 100%; top:0px; bottom:0px">
        <asp:Table ID="Table10" Height="32px" Width="100%" runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Left">
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnClose1" ToolTip="بستن کادر" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/close.png" />
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow HorizontalAlign="Right">
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTitle1" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
    <div  runat="server" id="divBody1">
    </div>
        </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but I had a very similar problem. I had some tabs working, then added a modalpopup extender and a panel, and suddendly my tabs dissappeared.

In my case, my modal popup panel's Visible property was set to "False" (which is not really necessary). Like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ModalPopupPanel" runat="server" CssClass="ModalPopupPanel" Visible="False">
```

When I deleted this property, the Tabs appeared. So it looks now like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="ModalPopupPanel" runat="server" CssClass="ModalPopupPanel">
```

I know you are not setting this property, but maybe you can try something like this to find what is causing the problem?

Sorry I cannot be of any more help.